# Conformal map of a double connected domain onto a domain whose boundary consists of

Tags: complex-analysis

*Prove the existence of a conformal map from a double connected domain, in **extended complex plane**, where none of the components is singleton, onto a domain whose boundary consists of two analytic Jordan Curve.*

It's a homework exercise that I find really hard. I know I should use the Riemann Mapping Theorem. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is a double-connected domain in the extended complex plane
$\hat{\Bbb C}$, let $A$ and $B$ be the connected components of
$\hat{\Bbb C} \setminus D$.

Then $D \cup A$ is simply-connected (and its complement is not a single
point), according to the Riemann mapping theorem there is a conformal
map $f$ from $D \cup A$  to the unit disk $\Bbb D$.

$f(A)$ is connected, so the Riemann mapping theorem can be applied
again to $\hat{\Bbb C} \setminus f(A)$.

The composition of these two mappings (restricted to $D$) has the desired property.

Comment: I didn't get it. How do we end up with a domain that it's boundary consists of two Jordan Curves? If you restrict f to D then D is mapped onto {Unit Disk}\f(A)? ( If correct) g maps from {Unit Disk}\f(A) to where?

Comment: @Mathitis: $g$ maps $\hat{\Bbb C} \setminus f(A)$ to the unit disk. The restriction of $g$ to $\Bbb D \setminus f(A)$ maps to a subset of the unit disk, bounded by two analytic Jordan curves (one if them is the circle $|z|=1$).

Comment: I can see why it's mapped to a subset of {Unit Disk}, but can't see why this subset is like an annulus

Comment: @Mathitis: $g(\{|z|=1\})$ is an analytic Jordan curve and that is one component of  the boundary of the image.

Comment: And the other component is the boundary of f(A)? I think I got it know, thank you very much for your time.